# Ref. request : book or survey about conducting experimental studies

Tags: reference-request, methodology, experiment-design

I am currently conducting researches that are almost mainly theoretical (I am a TCS researcher gone rogue = I also work on applying theory stuff to real life problems). In the future I plan to conduct several large experimental studies involving technical experiments AND human validation of the results.

I am a neophyte in conducting this kind of very large studies involving technicalities and "humanities". I ask around and search on the web for a textbook about this matter and do not find any comprehensive resource.

So the question : do you have any pointer to a book/survey/other explaining the whole process of a large scale experimental study? It can be from any domain.

Comment: Related: a question I had asked on stats.SE: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29332/a-course-in-experimental-design-for-data-miners - you might also consider looking there for answers.

Comment: Don't rely on (a) book(s) alone. Yes, there are some very good books, but it's a craft and you need expertise and general rules often have to be adapted to specific domains. You can develop that expertise, but that takes time (and resources, and trials). So I would strongly recommend to find someone who has a strong background in empirical studies in that area (publication record in peer-reviewed journals!) and try to work with that person. Second best strategy is to use the university service department (if you have it for empirical work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the classic in experimental social science methodology is [Shadish & Cook's "Experimental and Quasi-Experimental Designs for Generalized Causal Inference"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0395615569).

It covers various forms of experimental research design and also go into considerable detail in explaining the logic and practical steps of each.

Comment: A must-read for those interested in experimental research design. Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

The best book about experimental studies you can read is surely **[*Sidereus Nuncius*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereus_Nuncius)** by **[Galileo Galilei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei)**, the father of modern science.

That book was published first in 1610, but it's still very current. It explains to you how Galileo Galilei built his technologies (the telescope) and how he run up his experiments to discover new stars and planets.

Definetely, a **must-read** book for every scientist.

Comment: I don't question the historical relevance of the book (and I haven't read it), but I'm not sure this cover the requirements for modern-day experiment...would it be really useful for a scientist starting in the experiment domain?