# Data Collection in Academia: Insights?

Tags: phd, books

Data Collection is a primary objective in many academic fields and can be approached primarily through three different lenses - qualitative,quantitative and mixed methods.

With particular attention to computer science and HCI (human-computer interaction), what are some primary approaches to data collection? Specific references to primary, secondary and tertiary sources would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be a duplicate of [*“book or survey about conducting experimental studies”*](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/4784/2700)

Answer (score 3):

The first introductory text I used is [Survey Research Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534126723) by Babbie. It gave (and still serves as a refreshment of) a pretty comprehensive look to the whole process, and the writing and layout are quite easy to understand.

I'd also consider a Google search on different syllabi using phrase like "[research methods syllabus filetype:pdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=research+methods+syllabus+filetype%3Apdf)" and see what most instructors recommend. You can modify the search phrase to make it closer to your field; you can also change the `pdf` to other extensions such as `doc`, `docx`, or even `ppt` if you desire other types of document.

I'm sorry to say that we can't be ready to run a study just by one book. Common methods such as interview, focus group, and questionnaire are their own field of research: For interview and focus group, you'd have to expand into the field of communication and qualitative analysis. For questionnaire design, you may have to further tap into some psychological manifestation of questions, measurement theory, and item response theory.

To build a better foundation, I'd also recommend flipping through [Craft of Research](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226065669) by Booth et. al. and it will also pay off to befriend some statisticians or people major in statistics because you may need to learn something about probability-based sampling as well.